# Setting scan.all.resources for Swagger in JAXRS

Tags: annotations, swagger

I am using plain vanilla JAXRS in a provided Application Server with Swagger 1.5.18.  I can get the Swagger annotated classes to appear in the `swagger.json`, but I am having trouble setting the Swagger to scan for non annotated classes, those with just the `@Path` JAXRS annotations.

I currently have the `BeanConfig` in the Class that is extending `Application`.  I tried using a `Servlet` that extended `DefaultJaxrsConfig` with  `@WebInitParam(name="scan.all.resources", value="true")` but that did not work at all.

The [documentation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations-1.5.X) states that setting `ReaderConfig.scanAllResources` would achieve what I am looking for.  However, I am not sure of a good way to implement this.  Any suggestions?

Current configuration class:

```
@ApplicationPath("services") 
public class Configuration extends Application {

public Configuration() {
    BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
    beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.0");
    beanConfig.setTitle("SwaggerExample");
    beanConfig.setBasePath("/SwaggerExample/services");
    beanConfig.setResourcePackage("com.xxxxxx.swagger.jaxrs");
    beanConfig.setScan(true);
    beanConfig.setPrettyPrint(true);
}
```

Thanks, Brian

Answer (score 3):

I did find a way around the issue as posted in the Swagger [blog post](https://swagger.io/blog/customizing-your-auto-generated-swagger-definitions-in-1-5-x/), by implementing a ReaderListener.  However, I would think this could be set at the BeanConfig level.   Here is my solution:

```
@SwaggerDefinition
public class ApiDefinitions implements ReaderListener {

    @Override
    public void afterScan(Reader reader, Swagger swagger) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeScan(Reader reader, Swagger swagger) {
        ((DefaultReaderConfig) reader.getConfig()).setScanAllResources(true); 
    }
}
```

Brian